# how take rtsp in server and convert to mp4

Tags: python, server, stream, type-conversion, mp4

I would like to take the video stream (rtsp) from the DVR and send it to the server then convert it to .mp4 and send it to an application I'm developing.
how can I do all this?

possibly with python, do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

```
    1 import numpy as np
    2 import cv2
    3 
    4 cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp link')
    5 
    6 # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    7 fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    8 out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
    9 
   10 while(cap.isOpened()):
   11     ret, frame = cap.read()
   12     if ret==True:
   13         frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)
   14 
   15         # write the flipped frame
   16         out.write(frame)
   17 
   18         cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
   19         if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
   20             break
   21     else:
   22         break
   23 
   24 # Release everything if job is finished
   25 cap.release()
   26 out.release()
   27 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i am trying to use opencv:

- save the file,
- when I open the output file, it does not open (0byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pythonic way, but try to check out [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and its C-libraries `libav*`. FFmpeg allows you to encode/decode and mux/demux your stream. This awesome library supports a really wide range of different codecs and muxers/demuxers, check it out: [codecs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html), [formats](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html).

Here's a possible structure of your system:

`RTSP -> Transcoding Server -> VOD Server -> Client`

1. RTSP - you know.
2. Transcoding Server (FFmpeg) - FFmpeg server which accepts RTSP Stream and decodes it in .mp4 format (h264 + acc).
3. VOD Server (Video-On-Demand) - [Video-On-Demand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_on_demand) server. Just serve your .mp4 videos with nginx/apache/whatever.
4. Client - some of js-based video players or just native HTML5 `<video>` tag.

**Possible ways to make this structure works like a charm:**

1. Use python's `subprocess` library to call `ffmpeg-cli` on your transcoding server. As for me, really painful path.. **Not recommended.** Go next.
2. [PyAV](https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV). OpenSource Python bindings for `libav*` libraries. Still very poor functionality, but you can try to do something with it. **Not recommended in production.**
3. Use `libav*` library itself (without `ffmpeg-cli`). Just write your transcoding logic on C using `libavcodec / libavformat / libavdevice` and wrap it into `Python.Boost / Ctypes / Cython` and voila, call your hand-written C code directly from Python code. **Recommended, but requires skills with C and Python C-wraping libraries.**

**UPD:**

4. [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). Can't say much about this method, but I know that native OpenCV library for C++ has some new methods for encoding/decoding video on CUDA. Try to check out [this section](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) of official [OpenCV-Python Tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html).

Comment: @Rock, `VideoCapture(0)`: `0` in this command is your local device (webcam) with index 0. Try to pass your RTSP url, for example `VideoCapture('rtsp://your-url.com/')`.